# Welcome Message in Struts 2 running in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2, action-mapping

I have the following lines below in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But when I access http://localhost:8888 I received the error below:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name 
[] associated with context path [].
```

Isn't it be redirected to index.jsp? How to make welcome file work?

Answer (score 1):

After running server it is searching  for an action.
You should have an action in struts.xml that mapped to jsp file

Also add following in your `web.xml`

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the welcome file configured properly. The error message looks like a struts error message. It looks like you have a struts configuration problem. Check your action class configuration in your struts.xml file.

Comment: it says action name [], it means an empty action name?

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your `struts.xml` and enter this action as last action (only after all actions as a default action).

```
<action name="*">
    <result type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">Home.action</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Now this must be the last action and it will work like a default action for your application. You application will be redirected to this action if it didn't find any configured action.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below blank action to you struts.xml file in "/" package namespace and it will show the index.html when you will only try to access your url (like appid.app.com) and it will not show the error. Normally it will add a blank action and app engine will redirect the blank action to your welcome file.

```
    <action name="" class="com.candi.actions.Dashboard" method="noAction">
        <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

let explain further. just add blank action by providing blank "" as your action name and redirect your result to index.php which will solve your problem.